# Remove Blank Arrays from Filter Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, filter

I'm actually working on React Native which is based on React.js framework. So what I'm trying to here is create an object which has all the filter parameters in it from multiple arrays.
eg.

```
//This is not my Filter Object. 
//A state object in React Native is where you define your variables.
state = {
  holder: [], //Holds temp data which will be filled with filtered items
  allData: [], //Holds data of all the items
  
  //My filter parameters
  location: "",
  category: [],
  offers: [],
}
```

For easier understanding, I've filled my filter parameters for you: `location: "England"`, `category: ["Mens","Womens"]` and `offers: ["20%", "40%", "60%"]`

This is how my arrays would look like if all the 3 filter conditions have values assigned to them. Now this is the filter function that I'm applying for my array:

```
filterProducts = () => {
  //Packing all of my filter conditions in one Filter Object
  let query = {
    filter1: this.state.location,
    filter2: this.state.category,
    filter3: this.state.offers,
  }

  //Filter Logic on my Holder Array
  const filteredData = this.state.allData.filter(function (item) {
    return Object.entries(query).every(([key, value]) =>
      value.includes(item[key])
    );
  });
  console.log("Result: Filtered Array", filteredData);
  this.setState({ holder: filteredData });
}
```

For your easier understanding, my `query` object looks like:

```
let query = { 
  filter1: "England",
  filter2: ["Mens","Womens"],
  filter3: ["20%", "30%", "40%"],
}
```

So now what is my question? My filter logic only works if my Filter Object `query` looks like above. That is if all 3 filter parameters have some values assigned to them.

My filter logic breaks and returns me a `[]` array, if my Filter Object `query` becomes like this:

```
let query = {
  filter1: "England",
  filter2: ["Mens","Womens"],
  filter3: [], //Blank array inside object because user didn't pick any values
}
```

So my question to you all is:

1. How to *remove a blank array from an Object?*
2. Is there a way to change my filter logic which will skip filter3 if it's array is blank? Meaning, without removing blank arrays from my Filter Object, filter the array with only paramters which have some value assigned to them?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, I reckon.
You could use `Object.keys` to iterate over your values and append to new object according to the condition.

You could check the [example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-dzxced)

```
const onlyData = {}

Object.keys(query).forEach(filterKey => {
  const filterValue = query[filterKey];
  if (filterValue.length) onlyData[filterKey] = filterValue;
})
```

Comment: doesn't work. It renames my key to an integer which destroys the key pair matching, and thus I get returned a `[]` array. For context, this is the key pair that I need `{ "filter1" : "England" }`
What key pair I get after your suggestion: `{ "0" : "England" }`

Comment: I've updated the code. Is that what you're aiming for?